# New retrieval argument is not coming into PFC linkage arguments

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

I have added new retrieve arguments for my data window. When i am trying to launch the data window the pfc linkage arguments are not taking the new argument which i have added.

I get the following error

> Retrieve argument 2 does not match expected type

clearly indicating that it's trying to retrieve data window without the 2nd argument.

```
ls_dwobj = au_dc.DataObject
au_dc.SetTransObject(SQLCA)

ll_row_count = au_dc.Retrieve(aa_arg_array[1],aa_arg_array[2],aa_arg_array[3],aa_arg_array[4],aa_arg_array[5], aa_arg_array[6], aa_arg_array[7],aa_arg_array[8], aa_arg_array[9],aa_arg_array[10],aa_arg_array[11],aa_arg_array[12],
aa_arg_array[13], aa_arg_array[14], aa_arg_array[15],aa_arg_array[16],
aa_arg_array[17],aa_arg_array[18],aa_arg_array[19],aa_arg_array[20])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get the following error
>
> ```
> Retrieve argument 2 does not match expected type
> ```
>
> clearly indicating that it's trying to retrieve data window without the 2nd argument.

No. It is clearly indicating that the argument #2 of the `retrieve()` call (i.e. `aa_arg_array[2]`) is not of the type declared for the retrieval argument #2.
For example you have declared the argument to be an integer and you pass a string.